# Python SQL Select Syntax with variable in between

Tags: python, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a SQL statement that works in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_message` WHERE `id_order` = 111 ORDER BY id_message asc LIMIT 1
```

What is wrong with the following statement in Python:

```
cursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM ps_message WHERE id_order='%s'" % order["id_order"] " ORDER BY id_message asc LIMIT 1")
```

How should the syntax be in Python to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in string formatting. Should be:

```
cursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM ps_message WHERE id_order='%s' ORDER BY id_message asc LIMIT 1" % order["id_order"])
```

Using `format()` is also preferable over old-style string formatting. [Read more about it here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the order number as a query parameter.
e.g.

```
cursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM ps_message WHERE id_order=%s ORDER BY id_message asc LIMIT 1", [ order["id_order"] ])
```

Note that when using query parameters you don't put quotes around the %s.

This approach is recommended to avoid the risk of sql injection attacks.
It should also be more efficient if there are many queries.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html